# Is there a way to specify node modules that are in a folder outside the current project root?

Tags: typescript, node-modules

I have several lambdas in a project. They use a lambda layer, so the project structure looks like:

```
lambdas/
  create/
    index.ts
  delete/
    index.ts
  layer/
    nodejs/
      node_modules
```

I'd like to get each ts to compile using the layer/nodejs/node_modules directory.

I tried using

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*" : ["../utility_layer_1/nodejs"]
    }
  }
}
```

in my tsconfig, as well as

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "../utility_layer_1/nodejs",
    "paths": {
      "*" : ["."]
    }
  }
}
```

But I can't seem to get it to work.

I expected that by using base paths that I could get it to read from a different directory, but that appears to not be the case.

Answer (score 0):

The `paths` property is used to make non-relative imports relative (see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html). So you could import your utility layers like this

```
import { Something } from 'layer1'
```

when setting your `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "layer1": ["../utility_layer_1/nodejs"]
    }
  }
}
```

However, to compile everything in your utility folders, you are looking for the `include` property of your `tsconfig`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "layer1": ["../utility_layer_1/nodejs"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "../utility_layer_1/*.ts",
    "../utility_layer_1/nodejs/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Just run `tsc -w` in your base directory and compiling will be done on any save. I hope this answers your question.